# LinkedBlockingQueue and PriorityBlockingQueue in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java

I am working on `thread pool executor`, I obeserverd when i use    `PriorityBlockingQueue` it throws `ClassCastException` in code below and every things works fine if I choose `LinkedBlockingQueue` instead of `PriorityBlockingQueue` in code below.

Please help me understand this .

```
public class Test1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new PriorityBlockingQueue());
            executor.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            executor.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                }
            });
            executor.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: why are you doing multiple submit(), when exception is thrown at the first iteration itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of PriorityBlockingQueue whenever user inserts the specified element into the priority queue, ClassCastException is thrown, if the specified element cannot be compared with elements currently in the priority queue according to the priority queue's ordering.

However, There is no comparator required for LinkedBlockingQueue. So, there was no any exception.

Moreover, you can verify the same in the

`LinkedBlockingQueue.offer() and PriorityBlockingQueue.offer()` methods for more understanding.